# Why is Java's Object Stream returning the same object each time I call readObject?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

Forgive the pseudocode - my wireless networks is down, and I can't copy the code from my offline computer onto StackExchange at the moment.

I have two java applications, connected via java.net.* sockets. I am trying to pass "Message" objects from one to the other with via objectinput/output streams.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Class Message implements Serializable
{
  String text
  int data
     public Message(String txt, int dat)
     {
      this.text = txt;
      this.data = dat;
     }
     string toString()
     {
      return text + " " + data;
     }
}
```

**Server**:

Server has a Queue called Outbox

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 { 

 Message adding = new Message("Hello!",i);
 Outbox.add(temp)
 Message temp =     Outbox.poll();
 out.writeObject(temp);
  system.out.println(temp)
 }
```

**Client**:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  Message temp;
  temp = in.readObject()
  system.out.println(temp)
}
```

Now I hope it's apparent that I expect the consoles of each program to look identical. Instead, this is what I'm geting.

**Server**

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3...
```

**Client**

```
Hello 0
Hello 0
Hello 0
Hello 0...
```

So it looks like the Message Objects are being read but not removed from the Stream.

How can I unclog my streams and get them synchronized, as expected?

Comment: It's hard to say without more complete code... What happens if you change the first message to 50 or something that would stand out from 0 (which could just be a 'nothing')?

Comment: @Robert It shows `Hello 50`. The Object is definitely getting read correctly the *first* time.

Comment: Well that's a good sign. But I don't know what to say from here... without the actual code, it's impossible to find bugs. You've put what you meant to write, which looks correct, but without a real copy/paste there's no second set of eyes to catch silly typos...

Comment: are you sure you are doing `new` Message each time thru the loop in your real code, and not just reusing the message but changing the data?

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I've updated the question. It now properly reflects how I'm loading the messages (though it makes the pseudocode look absolutely asinine to do it this way)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the classic cause of this problem is sending the same object reference multiple times.  the Object stream impls preserve object reference identity and on the receiving end you will get the same object back on each readObject() call (*even if you have modified the object on the sending side!*).  your pseudo code is correct, however the question is whether or not it accurately reflects your actual code.

if your problem *is* a reference problem, you can solve the problem by either sending different object instances each time, or using`writeUnshared()` and/or calling `reset()` between each `writeObject()` call.  using `writeUnshared()` will force the main object to be a new object instance on the receiving end, but other objects which may be referenced by this object may still be shared references.  on the other hand, calling `reset()` will flush *all* cached objects on the receiving end, so all object references on the receiving end will be new references.  which one is better for managing the data over the wire is up to your use case, however, for long-running streams, it's always good to periodically call `reset()`, as this will free up memory which will build up over time (this is a common, but subtle "memory leak" when using Object streams).

Comment: It looks like it was indeed a reference problem! Is there a benefit to using WriteUnshared() vs. Reset()?

Comment: updated with some more info.  obviously, this is all in the javadocs.

Comment: Calling `writeUnshared` will still share other objects referenced by the original object. Nested back references to the original object wont work either. `writeUnshared` is not very useful.

Comment: But using reset() is increasing the size of output file having objects if the number of input file ( each line corresponding to one object lets say) is of the order or 2 GB or more. How can this be avoided.

Comment: @user3552407 - yes, it increases the size of the output because it is sending new copies of the data instead of just referencing the first copy.  if you _want_ shared references, then don't call `reset`.  if you _don't want_ shared references, then you need to do something, like calling `reset`.

Comment: @jtahlborn I want shared references, but in that case I am unable to access the data i.e. unable to read. Any solution for this except using reset() or writeUnshared() method for writing? writeUnshared() is taking too much of memory for large data.

Comment: @user3552407 - i'm confused.  if you want shared references, then don't call reset or writeUnshared.

Comment: @jtahlborn But then I am unable to read the objects. While reading using readObject(), I always get the first object I pushed in. A background here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854056/reading-and-writing-objects-in-a-file-in-java ) may be helpful for understanding my problem.

Comment: @user3552407 - you should ask your own question.  your comments here are confusing.  you said in an earlier comment "i want shared references".  in your latest comment you said "i don't want a reference to the first object (i.e. i don't want shared references)".