# Reading and writing objects in a file in java

Tags: java, object, serialization

I am trying to write objects in a file in java after serializing them. Currently, I am using `writeObject()` method. Reading objects using readObject() is always returning the first object. I am not sure whether this is the reason but I am not creating a new object every time I am writing to the file, I am just resetting the values of an existing object and calling writeObject(obj).

```
Student s1 = new Student(1,2);
// Assume I need to create an output file test.txt which has objects written to it.
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
int i=0; 
while ( i < MAX ) {
   s1.x = i;
   s1.y = i*10;  // assume that the student class has two fields x and y
   out.writeObject(s1);
   i++;
}
```

Now when I call `readObject()`, it always return the value of first object inserted. Probably because Object stream works by saving references to the object in the table, and I not creating new objects everytime, is this the reason?

Then I googled much and read about the behaviour of ObjectStream. So, I used `writeUnshared()` method for writing and able to read every object. But the memory consumption in this case is going in GB while writing large number of objects (10^9 or more ).(also taking more than 5 minutes or so).

The further answers I read said use `reset()` after writing the object to a file. This resets my stream but now the output file is now becoming very big in size. As I observed, when number of objects are very very large (say around 2 GB input objects), 5 GB file gets created.

What can be done in this case? Due to performance issues, I suppose I cannot use `writeUnshared()` and `reset()`. They how can I perform reading of the object if I use `writeObject()` only for writing. Any alternatives are also welcomed.
Or any other method which does the similar job can do the job. As I read, i heard of other serializers like XML, JSON, some Kryo of java and many others. But I am worried about the performance(memory and output size) of those.

Comment: I discourage using binary serialization. I guess you'd be better off serializing to XML or JSON. You should also add an [mcve] to your question.

Comment: You have correctly identified the reason. Have a look at `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`.

Comment: @EJP So, can I conclude that the file's big size is because the outputstream is getting reset every time due to which every object with new stream related information is being written to a file? If yes, is there any alternative to this?

Comment: @Fildor Added some more explanation. Also, serializing to XML or JSON, what output size shall be expected with the object having 1 or 2 float values and integer value. What if the number of objects are large (10^7 or more).  Will it not be more as compared to the current serializable technique?

Comment: If you care about size, you shouldn't be using Files at all. Consider using a DB for persistence.

Comment: @Fildor But the records are like logs which are saved in a file while the application runs, then? And with reset(), why the output size is becoming so large?

Comment: [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset--) : "Objects previously written to the stream will not be referred to as already being in the stream. **They will be written to the stream again.**" - So you write: 1, then 12, then 123 , 1234, 12345, ... instead of 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: "But the records are like logs" ... Logs can also be written into a DB ... And using XML/JSON representation even makes it possible to analyse them with external tools that do not depend on your code. But they most likely are bigger, yes.

Comment: @Fildor Consider we have n objects and trying to write (n+1)th object. Does that mean these n objects will be written to the stream again? Why? They were written to the file. I think I am getting something wrong here.

Comment: "Does that mean these n objects will be written to the stream again?" That's exactly what the docu sais. "Why?" because `reset()` is designed that way.

Comment: I suggest dropping the ObjectOutputStream.reset and research if you do the reading correctly.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the answers. Reading is working fine if I use writeUnshared() or reset(), but the issue then becomes either the memory usage or the large output file. That's why I am searching for either read or write alternatives like DB you suggested. Because I may have to deal with large amount of data.